# Having trouble slowing down fetch in javascript so as to avoid 429 errors

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I wonder if someone could help me.

I have a non-professional development license for a reverse geocoder within a javascript program where I am only allowed to do two requests
per second otherwise I get a 429 error. I have 3 sets of co-ordinates I wish to feed into the reverse geocoder and I get the first two
processed correctly but after that I get an error and the third one isn't processed. I thought that if I used the SetTimeout function either in the for
loop or in one of the lower level functions this would delay the requests enough to be able to process all 3 addresses but no matter where I
place the SetTimeout function it continues to get the 429 error. When I log the time to the console, I can see that the three calls to the
reverse geocoder happen at the same time. Can anyone suggest where I can place the timeout to slow down the requests enough?

Thanks (last attempted version of code below)

```
for (let i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++){
    // use a reverse geocode function to build a display address for each of the co-ordinates chosen
    SetTimeout(reverseGeocode(mapMarkers[i].getLatLng()), 1000);
        

};
      
   
function reverseGeocode(coords){
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    console.log("Into reverse geocoder " + time);
    let REVERSEURL = `https:....`
    let TOKEN = '.....'

    let url = `${REVERSEURL}key=${TOKEN}&lat=${coords.lat}&lon=${coords.lng}`;
    //do a reverse geocoding call
    getData(url, coords);

}

async function getData(url,coords) {
      try {
          const data = await getRequest(url);
          // create a display address with the first three elements containing something in the address dictionary
          let address = createAddressString(data.address, 3) +
              " ( " + coords.lat.toFixed(5) + ", " + coords.lng.toFixed(5) + " ) ";
          // Insert a div containing the address just built
          $("#addresses-container").append("<div class='request-page'>"+address+'</div>');
      } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
      }
}

async function getRequest(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
  } else {
      throw new Error("Bad response");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current logic is invoking the `reverseGeocode()` method immediately, as you pass the *response* from that function call to the timeout. You need to provide a function *reference* instead.

Even if you correct that issue, then you would instead delay *all* the requests by 1 second, but they would still get fired at the same time.

To stagger them you can use the index of the iteration to multiply the delay. For example, the following logic will fire 1 request every 250ms. This delay can be amended depending on what the rate limit is of your API provider. Also note that `SetTimeout()` needs to be `setTimeout()`

```
for (let i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => reverseGeocode(mapMarkers[i].getLatLng()), 250 * i);
}
```

Aside from the problem, it would be worth checking if the API can accept multiple lookups in a single request, which will alleviate the issue. Failing that, I'd suggest finding an alternative provider which allows more than 3 requests per N period.

Comment: The expression `reverseGeocode(mapMarkers[i].getLatLng())` gets called immediately. It doesn't resolve to a function.